# Comparation in MSQL two comparations

Tags: mysql, comparator

I have two tables (movies and genders).
"Genders" contains the gender with an ID to identify each (Action = 1, Drama = 2...etc.);
And Peliculas contains many columns with info plus a Gender id which identify the gender of the movie.

I am trying to do a selection where the years are Between xx and xx years (this is done) and at the same time bring up the movies with an specific gender.

I have try many things like this:

```sql
select *
from pelicula p
where anio between 1995 and 1996 
    and select id 
    from genero g 
    where g.nombre = "Action" = p.genero_id;
```

Comment: I suspect you mean "genres" not "genders". It's easier to work with tables with meaningful names.

Comment: Hi Arturo! Would definitely help to correct the title, in 2 respects: 1 - I believe you're asking about MySql not "MSQL".  2. Comparations is not an English word - probably you mean Comparisons?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks. English is not my mother tongue and i didn't know that difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a join.

```
Select * 
from pelicula p

Left Join genero g
p.genero_id = g.id 

where anio between 1995 and 1996 
and g.nombre = "Action";
```